# Smallest Ubuntu server self-contained installable .iso for development

Tags: virtualbox, aptitude, distro-recommendation

I'm looking for a development server to run in VirtualBox that can do run apt-get. That's it. I don't need anything else really.

I've started with the [Minimal CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) which is nice at 37Mb, but to install, it's been downloading stuff for 15+ minutes. I want to replicate this fast in other environments, so I want a small ISO that I can take on a USB stick. No desktop needed.

It must run this:

- sudo apt-get install mc
- sudo add-apt-repository

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at the [Ubuntu Mini Remix](http://www.ubuntu-mini-remix.org/).

> Ubuntu Mini Remix is a fully working Ubuntu livecd containing only the
>   minimal set of software to make the system work. Ubuntu Mini Remix ISO
>   image is around 200MB.

Comment: Only 200Mb, runs out of the box, but a bunch of things are broken. `sudo apt-get install mc`, and the critical `sudo add-apt-repository`. These work out of the box in Ubuntu server.

Comment: What are the error messages that you get? The commands should work out of the box...

Comment: I've [filed the issue here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mini-remix/+bug/1397919). Anyway, I've realized this is a Live CD. I need a distro that installs onto a hard disk (image) so I can do development on it.